# Why is my custom font rendering differently using font-face?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm using the following css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bariol_regularregular';
    src: url('Bariol_Regular.otf');
}
```

The font is being used and there are no errors on the page. When I add this custom font to text on the page it is visibly different to the default styling.

This is how the font should show:

[image]

However, this is how it is showing:

[image]

Pay particular attention to the apostrophe (') and the letter'g' where the most noticeable differences occur.

If I use a native app then the font shows correctly. The demo lettering on the site where I downloaded the font also displays correctly - https://www.dafontfree.net/freefonts-bariol-f64170.htm

Is there something I'm missing/not doing correctly?

Comment: 99% chance of bad url of the font

Comment: What do you mean? @TemaniAfif

Comment: i mean the url your are using may be wrong, no the good path

Comment: It's correct. No errors there. I've checked it. When I don't have the correct url it's styling is different.

Answer (score 1):

The typeface has multiple glyphs available for various characters so you'll need to find the character codes.

[image]

Comment: What app are you using to view that James?

Comment: I was using Adobe Illustrator. Out of my own personal internet on the subject, I came across this article which explains the alternative characters further. http://blog.fonts.com/2016/05/27/working-with-alternate-characters/